# Selenium: Use Multiple Strings in find_element_by_partial_link_text()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a link that contains either the *partial* strings **foo OR bar** in the link text.

Something like:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(['foo','bar']).click()
```

or if it was using a str.contains("foo|bar") style:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('foo|bar']).click()
```

Whats the right way to do this?

**EDIT**
Example HTML:

```
<a class="noprint" href="/Docs/Doc?request=62391270&amp;eCode=0XrIMF9p%2BMKSvdpdpqC5Nd3VFn4fB1eLXC3X0yHiYptOxprT0N%2BtjAu0%3D" target="_blank" type="submit">foo</a>
```

Or one with bar

```
<a class="noprint" href="/DocView/Doc?request=62391270&amp;eCode=CWJ1stkSu3qFZ1coGTEsM8ka4xqU0XrIMF9p%2BfB1eLXC3wh4xPFQnYwOqX0yHiYptOxprT0N%2BtjAu0%3D" target="_blank" type="submit">bar</a>
```

**EDIT2** The final working code was:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'foo') or contains(text(), 'bar')]").click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to create N conditional lines to do it, you can just use or operator `or` using xpath.

Example: `//a[contains(text(), 'aaaaa') or contains(text(), 'bbbbb')]`

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I think this doesn't do a partial text match though.

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='foo' or text()='bar']")` 

didnt work

Comment: This worked. My final code was:

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'foo') or contains(text(), 'bar')]").click()`

Answer (score 0):

I can get around it in the short term by doing this but it seems like a crappy solution:

```
try:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('foo').click()
except:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('bar').click()
```

**EDIT**
Example HTML:

```
<a class="noprint" href="/Docs/Doc?request=62391270&amp;eCode=0XrIMF9p%2BMKSvdpdpqC5Nd3VFn4fB1eLXC3X0yHiYptOxprT0N%2BtjAu0%3D" target="_blank" type="submit">foo</a>
```

Or one with bar

```
<a class="noprint" href="/DocView/Doc?request=62391270&amp;eCode=CWJ1stkSu3qFZ1coGTEsM8ka4xqU0XrIMF9p%2BfB1eLXC3wh4xPFQnYwOqX0yHiYptOxprT0N%2BtjAu0%3D" target="_blank" type="submit">bar</a>
```

Comment: Can you please share the html?

Comment: The HTML needs to be in the question... all bits of info that are needed to understand the scenario should be in the question.

Comment: Noted. Added to original question and accepted an answer.